# adjust TextView size to new text

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a textview between 2 other views inside a `ConstraintLayout`.
I set the text of the second one in the `onViewCreated` of my Fragment and later change it after some user input.
The first text works fine, but when i change it later i would expect its size to change with it, which of course would cause the view on its right to move a bit.
Instead the new text breaks down into 2 lines, when it's longer than the original...
How can i achieve that?
Here are the 3 Views:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/hevetica_font"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:text="@string/lbl"
    android:textColor="@color/FlatWhite"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/hevetica_font"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/FlatWhite"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView"
    android:text="change"
    />
```

and in the java code i change text using `textView.setText(text);`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want the text in the second view not to be split into 2 lines, you need to make the following changes:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="change" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if i see it correctly all you did, was set maxLines to 1. This prevents the line break but the size of the textview still doesn't adjust to the new text. instead it is now cut off

Comment: in my code i fixed and constraint, replace all code, in yor code was incorect constraint set, just copy all code

Comment: well i i only pasted those three views. There are of course other views above and beneath, which i reference...
Also you removed the font. why?

Comment: because i don't have this fonts, and i just removed it, you can add it back